# How to use search result after page reload to download csv

Tags: php, laravel

I have two functions - 1 showing the results and 1 to download results that are on page.

The problem is that I can't find a way how to download only the results. Instead when I hit Download button it downloads all records in database.

This is what I have in my controler

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = DB::table('downloads')
        ->select('user_id as downloader_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as count'))
        ->groupBy('user_id');
        
    if(isset($request->startDate) && isset($request->dateEnd)) {
        $user = $user->whereBetween(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(downloads.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"), [$request->startDate, $request->dateEnd]);
    } elseif (isset($request->startDate)) {
        $user = $user->where('created_at',$request->startDate);
    }
                    
    $works=DB::table('users')
        ->joinSub($user, 'downloads_byuser', function ($join) {
            $join->on('id', '=', 'downloads_byuser.downloader_id');
        })
        ->select('users.id as user_id', 'users.name as name', 'users.email as email', 'count')
        ->get();

    return view('admin.downloadsuser', compact("works"));
}

public function download(Request $request){
    
    $headers = array(
       // some headers
    );        

    //creating the download file
    $filename =  public_path("Downloads.csv");
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');

    //adding the first row
    fputcsv($handle, [
        "Email",
        "Downlaods",
    ]);

    //adding the data from the array
    foreach ($works as $each_user) {
        fputcsv($handle, [
            $each_user->email,
            $each_user->count,
        ]);

    }
    fclose($handle);
    
    return Response::download($filename, "Downloads.csv", $headers);
}
```

And this is in the blade

```
<form>                          
    <input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate">
    <input type="date" name="dateEnd" id="dateEnd">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Filter </button>             
</form>
<form action="{{ route('admin.works.download') }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Download </button>                                           
</form>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Downloads</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($works as $work)      
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $work->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $work->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $work->count }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the date when the search criteria are provided in the session, like this

```
\Session::put('startDate', $request->startDate);
\Session::put('dateEnd', $request->dateEnd);
```

After that in your download function retrieve the session dates. If none exists, the second parameter is returned instead.

```
$startDate = Session::get('startDate', '2022-02-11');
$dateEnd = Session::get('dateEnd', '2022-02-11');
```

You could just make them null, and have your query scope ignore them - which is essentially making the default export return all-time (unfiltered) records.

```
$startDate = Session::get('startDate', null);
$dateEnd = Session::get('dateEnd', null);
```

Or use carbon and return current date as default - `\Carbon\Carbon::parse()`